# Alternate approach for Thread.sleep() in JUnits verifying Scheduler tasks

Tags: java, junit, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a JUnit suite containing around 10-15 test cases. When i ran them, they execute one by one. Some of my test cases contain are verifying scheduled jobs, so they invoke the scheduled job and then wait for their completion. For that, i put 
**Thread.sleep()** in the code and after that i put assertion. e.g.,

```
public class TestCase1 extends JUnit {
    @Test
    public void testCase1(){
      //Do something
      //invoke scheduler task
      Thread.sleep(300 * 1000);
      //Do Assertion
    }
```

Now, i want to avoid this **Thread.sleep()** because it is contributing to the time of Test Suite execution. One approach came to my mind is to assertion code to be execute in parallel with other test cases. But, i am not sure if it will work or not.

Please help

Comment: Which scheduler do you use ? Can you write more code about "invoke scheduler task".

Comment: I m using quartz scheduler. But the problem is not in scheduler.
The problem is the time of JUnit execution.

Comment: I know, but quartz probably have some kind of listener to get notified when a schedule execution is over. Try to perform assertions in those listener, and use Synchronization objects to wait for the listener to get called.

Comment: If this is a _unit test_, you should be able to test that the scheduler's next trigger time is correct and that it kicks off an action, and then separately test  that the action it triggers has your desired effects. If this is an _integration test_ and you insist on testing the entire system, you may need to resign yourself to the delay (and the knowledge that you're testing a well-tested scheduler).